# PHP and no Soap action header

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl

I'm trying to call a remote web service, within my company.  For proprietary reasons I cannot provide the URL to the web service.  The web service has a single function called getItemField.  It is a small test service that I'm trying to run PHP against, the service description is as follows:

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://www.oracle.com/ws/MyFirstWebService" xmlns:intf="http://www.oracle.com/ws/MyFirstWebService" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns1="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.oracle.com/ws/MyFirstWebService">
<!--
WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.2alpha Built on Oct 23, 2007 (12:09:54 IST)
-->
<wsdl:types>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.oracle.com/ws/MyFirstWebService">
<import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
<complexType name="ArrayOf_xsd_string">
<complexContent>
<restriction base="soapenc:Array">
<attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[]"/>
</restriction>
</complexContent>
</complexType>
</schema>
</wsdl:types>
<message name="getItemFieldRequest">
<part name="args" type="impl:ArrayOf_xsd_string"/>
</message>
<message name="getItemFieldResponse">
<part name="getItemFieldReturn" type="soapenc:string"/>
</message>
<portType name="MyFirstWebService">
<operation name="getItemField" parameterOrder="args">
<input message="impl:getItemFieldRequest" name="getItemFieldRequest"/>
<output message="impl:getItemFieldResponse" name="getItemFieldResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="MyFirstWebServiceSoapBinding" type="impl:MyFirstWebService">
<wsdlsoap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="getItemField">
<wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input name="getItemFieldRequest">
<wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://first" use="encoded"/>
</input>
<output name="getItemFieldResponse">
<wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://www.oracle.com/ws/MyFirstWebService" use="encoded"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="MyFirstWebServiceService">
<port binding="impl:MyFirstWebServiceSoapBinding" name="MyFirstWebService">
<wsdlsoap:address location="http://myWebsite.com/services/MyFirstWebService"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

I can connect to the service just fine and print out the name of the single function and type, but when I try to call a function I get **'no SOAPAction header!'** error.  My PHP code to call the service function is as follows:

```
$options = array(
                // Dev
                'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2, 
                'exceptions'=>true, 
                'trace'=>1, 
                'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
                'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,

                // Credentials
                'login' => 'user', 
                'password' => 'pass'
            );        

// Connected successfully
            $client = new SoapClient( "http://myWebsite.com/services/MyFirstWebService?wsdl", $options );

    //Params
        $params = array( '123456' );

        //Options
        $options = array( 'soapaction' => '""' );

        //Call function (Both methods below throw the same 'no SOAPAction header!' error)
        //$result = $client->getItemField( new SoapParam($params, "getItemFieldRequest") );
        $result = $client->__soapCall( "getItemField", array('123456'), $options );
```

Based on the description of the service it doesn't appear to have a soapaction defined.  The line I see with soapAction is `<wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>`.  I tried to specify a blank soapAction since there's none defined, but that didn't seem to work.  Is the web service definition itself incomplete?  Or am I missing some parameter in my client-side application call?  Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Tried to specify the method name as the soap action, but htat didn't work.

```
    //Params
    $params = array( '123456' );

    //Options
    $options = array( 'soapaction' => 'getItemField' );

    //Call function (STILL THROWS 'no SOAPAction header!')
    $result = $client->__soapCall( "getItemField", $params, $options );
```

What am I supposed to do if no soapAction is specified in the wsdl, i.e. if it's set to "".

Comment: Any update on that? I am facing the same issue when trying to connect through curl on a webservice that I can connect to through Zend soap, so I suppose its related with some options or headers.

Comment: Isn't the SOAPAction header related to the HTTP header? Check http://www.oreillynet.com/xml/blog/2002/11/unraveling_the_mystery_of_soap.html

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, but I was using [`cURL`](http://us.php.net/curl) and not the [`SoapClient`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php), though the solution may be the same.

When sending a request to the end service, you have to send a header specifying the `Content-Type`. In this header, you can also specify the `action`, or "soap action".

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="[soap action goes here]"';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

In my case, and what appears to be the same as yours, the wsdl lists the following:

```
<wsdl:operation name="getProducts">
    <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
    <!-- trimmed -->
</wsdl:operation>
```

At first, I see `soapAction=""`, so I set `action=""` in the headers being sent. This failed. The correct data that goes into the header is the `operation`, making it `action="getProducts"`.

Based on the manual for [`SoapClient`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) and the answer to [php using SOAP with a different SoapAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255637/php-using-soap-with-a-different-soapaction), your request should have worked with:

```
$client = new SoapClient( "http://myWebsite.com/services/MyFirstWebService?wsdl", $options );
$result = $client->__soapCall( "getItemField", array('123456') );
```

Did you ever omit the `$options` sent to `__soapCall()` to simply not specify an action (rather than passing in a blank one)?

Answer (score -1):

Its difficult to help without having all the details necessary but I will advise you try the following:

```
//Replace accordingly: see PHP Manual
//(http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapheader.soapheader.php)

$header = new SoapHeader($namespace, $name, $data, $mustunderstand, $actor);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

//Main soap call follows....
```

before making the call to the soap service.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Why the downvote? Its really rude both to @profnotime and to everybody who comes here searching for an answer...

Comment: SoapHeader is for populating the <SOAP-ENV:Header/> section of the SOAP request. It does not set a HTTP header.