# php using SOAP with a different SoapAction

Tags: php, soap

I'm working with a WSDL that has a different SOAP Action in the header to the one I would expect.  At the moment when I call the web service, I just get like a .NET description site of a web service.  In this instance it's

```
https://preprod.squidcard.com/ytm/sQuidpages/sQuidPWS.asmx
```

What URL should I actually call to get to the getPurseBalance() method as the option in the SOAP Action from the WSDL doesn't seem to be defined, is there anyway I can determine this or should I go to the web service provider?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call a URL, you should post a XML to this direct same page. To know what to send to the web service you can check your URL:

https://preprod.squidcard.com/ytm/sQuidpages/sQuidPWS.asmx?op=getPurseBalance

Here you can also view your SoapAction and other headers to be send:

```
POST /ytm/sQuidpages/sQuidPWS.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: preprod.squidcard.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "https://secure.squidcard.com/getPurseBalance"
```

If you don't want to create XML manually you can also use the SoapClient class from PHP. You can find more information here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://preprod.squidcard.com/ytm/sQuidpages/sQuidPWS.asmx?WSDL");
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());

$client->__soapCall("getPurseBalance", array('your parameters'));
```

Comment: Ah, that's what I did, I sent the POST contents to https://preprod.squidcard.com/ytm/sQuidpages/sQuidPWS.asmx with all the XML the SOAP handler would expect.

Comment: So you should use specific headers with your request, for example the valid SoapAction. This you can find via a WSDL file, also i would recommend using the SoapClient class. This reads out your WSDL file!

Comment: Ah ok, that's sort of my problem, I'm trying to find out what the valid SoapAction url is.  This doesn't appear to be in the XML, should I contact the provider or is there someway I can determine it.

Comment: You probably can find out via the SoapClient library, you can also use a program called SoapUI to find out, both of them reads out your WSDL file.

Comment: I have edited my post to show you what headers to send, inclusively the SoapAction

Comment: Ok... and _how exactly_ are you supposed to use __soapCall so SOAPAction is set correctly? Without this info, the answer is incomplete. Downvoting...

Comment: People like you ruin this community, if you think my answer is incomplete, you should make additions to it. Most people are smart enough to see it is not incomplete though.

Answer (score 0):

see this http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setlocation.php

I think you should use

```
$client->__setLocation('https://preprod.squidcard.com/ytm/sQuidpages/sQuidPWS.asmx');
```